# matplotlib doesn't appear using pydev/eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, matplotlib

i am using matplotlib with pydev in eclipse and when i run the following script the matplotlib window wont appear:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([2,1,3])
plt.ion()
plt.draw()

input('something')
```

when i'm executing this script in a terminal everything works fine.

i use the Qt4Agg backend. when i change this to TkAgg the graph will appear but it's frozen.

when i remove plt.ion() everything works fine.

dows someone has an idea what causes this problem?

Comment: Which method are you running the script with in PyDev (run as, debug as, console, etc.) The correct answer depends on it.

Comment: it doesn't matter which method i use (run as, debug as) both  have the same result